# Does clang-tidy make clang-check redundant?

Tags: clang, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

Both of these tools seem to share some common goals and while the [documentation of clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) is quite explicit about its capabilities, [clang-check's](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCheck.html) is a bit sparse.

It would be nice if I could run only one of these tools while having the same checks in place. Obviously, clang-tidy has some features which are absent in clang-check, so the question is:

Is there a combination of checks for clang-tidy that includes all of the features of `clang-check -analyze`?

Answer (score 7):

After looking at the sources of both tools, `clang-check -analyze` instantiate an `AnalysisASTConsumer` from the StaticAnalyzer lib [through here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/2e23251d3e91db37d19bf876f91b85059ead2491/include/clang/StaticAnalyzer/Frontend/AnalysisConsumer.h#L38).

[clang-tidy also does it](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/0ae5fe435fe0cc658ef0bca8769b022d963b4498/clang-tidy/ClangTidy.cpp#L389) if analyzer options are supplied.

So, everything seems to indicate that `clang-tidy -check='clang-analyzer-*'` is equivalent to `clang-check -analyze`.

Comment: Looks like it is broken. I took code from https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html, put it in my code and ran `clang-tidy` with  `clang-analyzer-*`. However I dont see any output related to warnings the above code supposed to produce