# Does clang-tidy make scan-build redundant?

Tags: clang, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy, scan-build

I have a project that currently uses both scan-build and clang-tidy (enabled via CMake).

If I enable `clang-analyzer-*` in my set of clang-tidy checks, is the usage of scan-build redundant?

For reference, there is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943781/does-clang-tidy-make-clang-check-redundant) about the usage of clang-tidy with clang-check.

Answer (score 3):

These are the available checks reported by `scan-build --help` (the "+" indicates that the check is enabled by default):

```
 + core.CallAndMessage           Check for logical errors for function calls and Objective-C message expressions (e.g., uninitialized arguments, null function pointers)
 + core.DivideZero               Check for division by zero
 + core.NonNullParamChecker      Check for null pointers passed as arguments to a function whose arguments are references or marked with the 'nonnull' attribute
 + core.NullDereference          Check for dereferences of null pointers
 + core.StackAddressEscape       Check that addresses to stack memory do not escape the function
 + core.UndefinedBinaryOperatorResult
                                 Check for undefined results of binary operators
 + core.VLASize                  Check for declarations of VLA of undefined or zero size
 + core.uninitialized.ArraySubscript
                                 Check for uninitialized values used as array subscripts
 + core.uninitialized.Assign     Check for assigning uninitialized values
 + core.uninitialized.Branch     Check for uninitialized values used as branch conditions
 + core.uninitialized.CapturedBlockVariable
                                 Check for blocks that capture uninitialized values
 + core.uninitialized.UndefReturn Check for uninitialized values being returned to the caller
 + cplusplus.InnerPointer        Check for inner pointers of C++ containers used after re/deallocation
 + cplusplus.Move                Find use-after-move bugs in C++
 + cplusplus.NewDelete           Check for double-free and use-after-free problems. Traces memory managed by new/delete.
 + cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks      Check for memory leaks. Traces memory managed by new/delete.
 + cplusplus.PlacementNew        Check if default placement new is provided with pointers to sufficient storage capacity
 + cplusplus.PureVirtualCall     Check pure virtual function calls during construction/destruction
 + deadcode.DeadStores           Check for values stored to variables that are never read afterwards
   fuchsia.HandleChecker         A Checker that detect leaks related to Fuchsia handles
 + nullability.NullPassedToNonnull
                                 Warns when a null pointer is passed to a pointer which has a _Nonnull type.
 + nullability.NullReturnedFromNonnull
                                 Warns when a null pointer is returned from a function that has _Nonnull return type.
   nullability.NullableDereferenced
                                 Warns when a nullable pointer is dereferenced.
   nullability.NullablePassedToNonnull
                                 Warns when a nullable pointer is passed to a pointer which has a _Nonnull type.
   nullability.NullableReturnedFromNonnull
                                 Warns when a nullable pointer is returned from a function that has _Nonnull return type.
   optin.cplusplus.UninitializedObject
                                 Reports uninitialized fields after object construction
   optin.cplusplus.VirtualCall   Check virtual function calls during construction/destruction
   optin.mpi.MPI-Checker         Checks MPI code
   optin.osx.OSObjectCStyleCast  Checker for C-style casts of OSObjects
   optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.EmptyLocalizationContextChecker
                                 Check that NSLocalizedString macros include a comment for context
   optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.NonLocalizedStringChecker
                                 Warns about uses of non-localized NSStrings passed to UI methods expecting localized NSStrings
   optin.performance.GCDAntipattern
                                 Check for performance anti-patterns when using Grand Central Dispatch
   optin.performance.Padding     Check for excessively padded structs.
   optin.portability.UnixAPI     Finds implementation-defined behavior in UNIX/Posix functions
   osx.API                       Check for proper uses of various Apple APIs
   osx.MIG                       Find violations of the Mach Interface Generator calling convention
   osx.NumberObjectConversion    Check for erroneous conversions of objects representing numbers into numbers
   osx.OSObjectRetainCount       Check for leaks and improper reference count management for OSObject
   osx.ObjCProperty              Check for proper uses of Objective-C properties
   osx.SecKeychainAPI            Check for proper uses of Secure Keychain APIs
   osx.cocoa.AtSync              Check for nil pointers used as mutexes for @synchronized
   osx.cocoa.AutoreleaseWrite    Warn about potentially crashing writes to autoreleasing objects from different autoreleasing pools in Objective-C
   osx.cocoa.ClassRelease        Check for sending 'retain', 'release', or 'autorelease' directly to a Class
   osx.cocoa.Dealloc             Warn about Objective-C classes that lack a correct implementation of -dealloc
   osx.cocoa.IncompatibleMethodTypes
                                 Warn about Objective-C method signatures with type incompatibilities
   osx.cocoa.Loops               Improved modeling of loops using Cocoa collection types
   osx.cocoa.MissingSuperCall    Warn about Objective-C methods that lack a necessary call to super
   osx.cocoa.NSAutoreleasePool   Warn for suboptimal uses of NSAutoreleasePool in Objective-C GC mode
   osx.cocoa.NSError             Check usage of NSError** parameters
   osx.cocoa.NilArg              Check for prohibited nil arguments to ObjC method calls
   osx.cocoa.NonNilReturnValue   Model the APIs that are guaranteed to return a non-nil value
   osx.cocoa.ObjCGenerics        Check for type errors when using Objective-C generics
   osx.cocoa.RetainCount         Check for leaks and improper reference count management
   osx.cocoa.RunLoopAutoreleaseLeak
                                 Check for leaked memory in autorelease pools that will never be drained
   osx.cocoa.SelfInit            Check that 'self' is properly initialized inside an initializer method
   osx.cocoa.SuperDealloc        Warn about improper use of '[super dealloc]' in Objective-C
   osx.cocoa.UnusedIvars         Warn about private ivars that are never used
   osx.cocoa.VariadicMethodTypes Check for passing non-Objective-C types to variadic collection initialization methods that expect only Objective-C types
   osx.coreFoundation.CFError    Check usage of CFErrorRef* parameters
   osx.coreFoundation.CFNumber   Check for proper uses of CFNumber APIs
   osx.coreFoundation.CFRetainRelease
                                 Check for null arguments to CFRetain/CFRelease/CFMakeCollectable
   osx.coreFoundation.containers.OutOfBounds
                                 Checks for index out-of-bounds when using 'CFArray' API
   osx.coreFoundation.containers.PointerSizedValues
                                 Warns if 'CFArray', 'CFDictionary', 'CFSet' are created with non-pointer-size values
   security.FloatLoopCounter     Warn on using a floating point value as a loop counter (CERT: FLP30-C, FLP30-CPP)
   security.insecureAPI.DeprecatedOrUnsafeBufferHandling
                                 Warn on uses of unsecure or deprecated buffer manipulating functions
 + security.insecureAPI.UncheckedReturn
                                 Warn on uses of functions whose return values must be always checked
   security.insecureAPI.bcmp     Warn on uses of the 'bcmp' function
   security.insecureAPI.bcopy    Warn on uses of the 'bcopy' function
   security.insecureAPI.bzero    Warn on uses of the 'bzero' function
   security.insecureAPI.decodeValueOfObjCType
                                 Warn on uses of the '-decodeValueOfObjCType:at:' method
 + security.insecureAPI.getpw    Warn on uses of the 'getpw' function
 + security.insecureAPI.gets     Warn on uses of the 'gets' function
 + security.insecureAPI.mkstemp  Warn when 'mkstemp' is passed fewer than 6 X's in the format string
 + security.insecureAPI.mktemp   Warn on uses of the 'mktemp' function
   security.insecureAPI.rand     Warn on uses of the 'rand', 'random', and related functions
   security.insecureAPI.strcpy   Warn on uses of the 'strcpy' and 'strcat' functions
 + security.insecureAPI.vfork    Warn on uses of the 'vfork' function
 + unix.API                      Check calls to various UNIX/Posix functions
 + unix.Malloc                   Check for memory leaks, double free, and use-after-free problems. Traces memory managed by malloc()/free().
 + unix.MallocSizeof             Check for dubious malloc arguments involving sizeof
 + unix.MismatchedDeallocator    Check for mismatched deallocators.
 + unix.Vfork                    Check for proper usage of vfork
 + unix.cstring.BadSizeArg       Check the size argument passed into C string functions for common erroneous patterns
 + unix.cstring.NullArg          Check for null pointers being passed as arguments to C string functions
   valist.CopyToSelf             Check for va_lists which are copied onto itself.
   valist.Uninitialized          Check for usages of uninitialized (or already released) va_lists.
   valist.Unterminated           Check for va_lists which are not released by a va_end call.
   webkit.NoUncountedMemberChecker
                                 Check for no uncounted member variables.
   webkit.RefCntblBaseVirtualDtor Check for any ref-countable base class having virtual destructor.
   webkit.UncountedLambdaCapturesChecker
                                 Check uncounted lambda captures.
```

And this is the output of `clang-tidy --list-checks | grep clang-analyzer-`:

```
    clang-analyzer-apiModeling.StdCLibraryFunctions
    clang-analyzer-apiModeling.TrustNonnull
    clang-analyzer-apiModeling.google.GTest
    clang-analyzer-apiModeling.llvm.CastValue
    clang-analyzer-apiModeling.llvm.ReturnValue
    clang-analyzer-core.CallAndMessage
    clang-analyzer-core.CallAndMessageModeling
    clang-analyzer-core.DivideZero
    clang-analyzer-core.DynamicTypePropagation
    clang-analyzer-core.NonNullParamChecker
    clang-analyzer-core.NonnilStringConstants
    clang-analyzer-core.NullDereference
    clang-analyzer-core.StackAddrEscapeBase
    clang-analyzer-core.StackAddressEscape
    clang-analyzer-core.UndefinedBinaryOperatorResult
    clang-analyzer-core.VLASize
    clang-analyzer-core.builtin.BuiltinFunctions
    clang-analyzer-core.builtin.NoReturnFunctions
    clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.ArraySubscript
    clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.Assign
    clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.Branch
    clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.CapturedBlockVariable
    clang-analyzer-core.uninitialized.UndefReturn
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.InnerPointer
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.Move
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDelete
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.PlacementNew
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.PureVirtualCall
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.SelfAssignment
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.SmartPtrModeling
    clang-analyzer-cplusplus.VirtualCallModeling
    clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores
    clang-analyzer-fuchsia.HandleChecker
    clang-analyzer-nullability.NullPassedToNonnull
    clang-analyzer-nullability.NullReturnedFromNonnull
    clang-analyzer-nullability.NullabilityBase
    clang-analyzer-nullability.NullableDereferenced
    clang-analyzer-nullability.NullablePassedToNonnull
    clang-analyzer-nullability.NullableReturnedFromNonnull
    clang-analyzer-optin.cplusplus.UninitializedObject
    clang-analyzer-optin.cplusplus.VirtualCall
    clang-analyzer-optin.mpi.MPI-Checker
    clang-analyzer-optin.osx.OSObjectCStyleCast
    clang-analyzer-optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.EmptyLocalizationContextChecker
    clang-analyzer-optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.NonLocalizedStringChecker
    clang-analyzer-optin.performance.GCDAntipattern
    clang-analyzer-optin.performance.Padding
    clang-analyzer-optin.portability.UnixAPI
    clang-analyzer-osx.API
    clang-analyzer-osx.MIG
    clang-analyzer-osx.NSOrCFErrorDerefChecker
    clang-analyzer-osx.NumberObjectConversion
    clang-analyzer-osx.OSObjectRetainCount
    clang-analyzer-osx.ObjCProperty
    clang-analyzer-osx.SecKeychainAPI
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.AtSync
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.AutoreleaseWrite
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.ClassRelease
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.Dealloc
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.IncompatibleMethodTypes
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.Loops
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.MissingSuperCall
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NSAutoreleasePool
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NSError
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NilArg
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.NonNilReturnValue
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.ObjCGenerics
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.RetainCount
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.RetainCountBase
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.RunLoopAutoreleaseLeak
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.SelfInit
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.SuperDealloc
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.UnusedIvars
    clang-analyzer-osx.cocoa.VariadicMethodTypes
    clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.CFError
    clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.CFNumber
    clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.CFRetainRelease
    clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.containers.OutOfBounds
    clang-analyzer-osx.coreFoundation.containers.PointerSizedValues
    clang-analyzer-security.FloatLoopCounter
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.DeprecatedOrUnsafeBufferHandling
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.SecuritySyntaxChecker
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.UncheckedReturn
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.bcmp
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.bcopy
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.bzero
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.decodeValueOfObjCType
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.getpw
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.gets
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.mkstemp
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.mktemp
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.rand
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.strcpy
    clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.vfork
    clang-analyzer-unix.API
    clang-analyzer-unix.DynamicMemoryModeling
    clang-analyzer-unix.Malloc
    clang-analyzer-unix.MallocSizeof
    clang-analyzer-unix.MismatchedDeallocator
    clang-analyzer-unix.Vfork
    clang-analyzer-unix.cstring.BadSizeArg
    clang-analyzer-unix.cstring.CStringModeling
    clang-analyzer-unix.cstring.NullArg
    clang-analyzer-valist.CopyToSelf
    clang-analyzer-valist.Uninitialized
    clang-analyzer-valist.Unterminated
    clang-analyzer-valist.ValistBase
    clang-analyzer-webkit.NoUncountedMemberChecker
    clang-analyzer-webkit.RefCntblBaseVirtualDtor
    clang-analyzer-webkit.UncountedLambdaCapturesChecker
```

The clang-tidy version is 12.0.0.

So, it seems like scan-build is a subset of clang-tidy (as far as the available checks are concerned), and the answer to your question is "yes".